# Drag and Drop not working for Ubuntu 20.04 VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, clipboard, 20.04

```
Host       : Windows 10  
VirtualBox : v6.1.6
Guest      : Ubuntu 20.04
```

In the same version of VirtualBox I have two different versions of Ubuntu - 18.04 and 20.04.

For Ubuntu 18.04 -
`1. Shared ClipBoard - Works fine (Bi-Directional).

 2. Drag & Drop - Works fine (Bi-Directional).`

For Ubuntu 20.04 -
`1. Shared ClipBoard - Works fine (Bi-Directional).

 2. Drag & Drop -`**Not Working at all**.
It shows **forbidden icon** when trying Drag n Drop from Host to Guest. For Guest to Host it shows nothing.

What i tried -
1. Installed VirtualBox Extension Pack v6.1.6
2. Ran - `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic`
3. Installed GuestAdditions.

But, no luck yet.

Comment: Modern versions of Ubuntu have much of the tooling installed by default which may conflict with the GuestAdditions.   Also Ubuntu 20.04 just came out, so perhaps wait a bit until there has been an official VirtualBox release after that to give the VirtualBox folks a chance to check everything works.  You may in the mean time consider raising an issue to let them know the documentation for Ubuntu may need updating.

Comment: Thanks @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. I have already raised this issue to VirtualBox forum

Comment: Virtualbox has not support PPA for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa. check here http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/

Comment: @ajcg Yes, i saw the list. It's not there. Thank You though.

Comment: sorry. It is not a PPA. It's a third-party repository

Answer (score 6):

You can only drop inside folders now. You can no longer drop directly on the ubuntu desktop. If anyone has figured out how to enable this.

Please tell! **You however can make it land in the desktop by navigating to the Desktop folder in the "Files" app.**

Also to install the guest additions cd on a clean ubuntu vbox install now you must first run following commands and install them:

```
sudo apt install gcc
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc make perl dkms
reboot
```

Now you can insert guest additions cd.

Answer (score 1):

I come to this question while facing almost the same issue.

## TL;DR

Make sure to install [VirtualBox guest additions CD](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-install)

## Versos answer

##### My Specs

```
Host: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 
Guest: Windows 10 1909
VirtualBox: 6.1.22 r144080 (Qt5.12.8)
```

##### Solution

0. Shutdown the guest machine, if it's running

###### In VirtualBox application (host):

1. Select the Guest Machine
2. GO to: General > Advenced :
3. chose the Drag'n'Drop option that you want (eg. Host to Guest)
4. Press OK
5. Start the Guest Machine

###### In the Guest Machine:

Install VirtualBox guest additions CD, as follow:

1. Click on the **Devices** option given in the Menu of the VirtualBox
2. then on the **Insert Guest Additions CD image**
3. **Run the software**, on the virtual CD.
4. Restart the Guest Machine.

This process should works for Ubuntu(Host)/Windows(Guest) or the inverse.